# pandas dataframe add dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

for example two dataframe

```
     a              b    c                                
0    1         0    2    7
1    2         1    3    6
2    3         2    4    5
```

i want to get

```
     a     b    c                                
0    1     2    7   
1    2     3    6    
2    3     4    5
```

if dataframe has to mant colums

Seems to be somewhat difficult

Comment: `df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` is what you want

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.concat()` with `axis=1`, see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([
  [1],
  [2],
  [3],
], columns=["a"])

df_2 = pd.DataFrame([
  [2, 7],
  [3, 6],
  [4, 5],
], columns=["b", "c"])

df_3 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)

print(df_3)
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  7
1  2  3  6
2  3  4  5
```